# Android get facebook username exception only the original thread that created a view hierarchy

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

i  working facebook api in android. i successfully can sing in in facebook and  try to check facebook user name
i wrote some code but i have

```
only the original thread that created a view hierarchy
```

exception
this is a my code:

```
public void LoginFacebook() {

    mFacebook.authorize(this, mPermissions, new LoginDialogListener());

}

private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        SessionStore.save(mFacebook, getApplicationContext());

        getProfileInformation();

    }

    public void onCancel() {
        SessionEvents.onLoginError("Action Canceled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public void getProfileInformation() {

    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new BaseRequestListener() {

        @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.e("Profile", response);

            String json = response;
            try {
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                facebook_userid = profile.getString("id");

                facebook_username = profile.getString("name");
                facebook_username = facebook_username.replace("%20", " ");

                fb_name.setText(facebook_username);



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

what am i doing wrong. i can sing in but i can't to show username in textview.
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onComplete method you're trying to set the text of a UI element. Your onComplete method is getting called from a background(non main/UI thread). Any time you make a UI change, it must be on the UI thread. Try inserting a runOnUIThread call in your onComplete like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
fb_name.setText(facebook_username);
} 
});
```

Note: you will need to make variables declared outside the runnable final (ex: facebook_username)

Also note: most (if not all) web based calls will return on a background thread so you might need to use runOnUIThread frequently.